# Github Error while syncing Git history: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value Databrick integration error

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks, devops-services

I am following a guide on how to integrate Azure DevOps CI/CD with Azure Databricks.
https://medium.com/@bedatse/azure-devops-ci-cd-with-azure-databricks-and-data-factory-part-1-c05a44536a8e

Everything is working fine up to Step 3-2, where I need to link my workbook to Azure DevOps Repo, which should be the URL of my git repository.

I have set the Path in Git Repo to the location where I want Databricks to save my notebook inside the repository.
[image]

However, when I save I get the following Git Failed message;

```
Error while syncing Git history: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')? at [Source: ????<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">???? ?? ????<html lang="en-US">??<head><title>?? ?? Azure DevOps Services | Sign In?? ??</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" />?? <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico"/>???? <link data-bundlelength="508491" data-bundlename="commoncss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M159_20191007.24/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-commoncss-vFEXRww04Ui9f9-agwRu1-KcB8LHGV2h4if73yu-SgCA=" data-includedstyles="jQueryUI-Modified;Core;Splitter;PivotView" href="/_static/tfs/M159_20191007.24/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-commoncss-vdGeUpct-nfzYfTJ4ZaPoC5_RMPHB-2NPspm7OsZ3cA8=" rel="stylesheet" />??<link data-bundlelength="116152" data-bundlename="viewcss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M159_2019
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated

Comment: You can reproduce the issue by using Fiddler to capture the records the analyze its detailed error. If convenient, you could share part of it here.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT, thanks for reaching out. I have decided to not use Databricks Workspace as an IDE. Instead, I will simply export Notebooks to my local drive and us Visual Studio upload files to Azure Devops repository

Comment: ok. If needed, you can use Fiddler to capture the analyze it firstly;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had this raised by a customer recently, I've just run through the lab myself to see if I could replicate this error. I didn’t have any major issues but did notice a couple of things which may help.

I initially observed `Error linking with Git`, albeit with different error text but this may be an additional blocker worth investigating… Since this course material was written, Azure DevOps and GitHub no longer name the default branch as `master` for new repositories, and use `main` instead. Azure Databricks still seems to default to `master` as per your screenshot, so it might be worth checking this.

But in addition to the above, I would also double check that neither the “Link” nor “Path in Git Repo” fields contain the unexpected character identified in the second part of the error message:

> `Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)):`

The instructions contain the following note:

> **Note**
> format of URL is
> `http://dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/<myProject>/_git/<myRepo>`
> which differs from the URL of the repo displayed in Azure DevOps
> `http://dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/_git/<myRepo>`

I was able to reproduce your error by simply placing one or more of the `<` `>` braces around some of the strings which need replacing with your own values.